# Transverse intersection of two divisors

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $X$ be a smooth variety and $D_1$ and $D_2$ are two smooth divisors which intersect transversely. Assume also that $D_1\cap D_2$ is irreducible. Is it true that $\mathcal{O}(-D_1)|_{D_2}\cong \mathcal{O}_{D_2}(-D_1\cap D_2)$?

or is it $\mathcal{O}(-D_1)|_{D_2}\cong \mathcal{O}_{D_2}(-n\cdot D_1\cap D_2)$ for some integer n?

Comment: $n=1$, but you should understand intersection scheme-theoretically.